# How to access ViewWillAppear/ViewDidDisappear in ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, WkWebViewRenderer>?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to port an Android existing custom ViewRenderer to iOS.
I'm using version 4.8 of Xamarin.Forms.

Specifically, I need to match Android's **OnAttachedToWindow** & **OnDetachedFromWindow**.

The Android Code is like the following:

```
public partial class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>
{
    protected override void OnAttachedToWindow()
    {
        base.OnAttachedToWindow();
        ...
    }
    protected override void OnDetachedFromWindow()
    {
        base.OnDetachedFromWindow();
        ...
    }
}
```

According to [this link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/240043/#Comment_240043), I would need to override ViewWillAppear which is the iOS equivalent to OnAttachedToWindow.

The custom Renderer for iOS is the following:

```
public partial class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, WkWebViewRenderer>, IWKScriptMessageHandler
{
}
```

But the overrides are not available.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewWillAppear` and `ViewWillDisappear` are the life cycle method of **UIViewController**.So you could create the custom renderer of **ContentPage**

#### in the ContentPage that contains the WebView

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UIKit;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using App1;
using App1.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage),typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
namespace App1.iOS
{
    public class MyPageRenderer:PageRenderer
    {

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            MessagingCenter.Send<Object,UIViewController>(this,"ViewWillAppear",this); // send message when  the method been called .
        }

        public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);

            MessagingCenter.Send<Object, UIViewController>(this, "ViewWillDisappear", this);

            

        }

    }
}
```

#### in WebViewRenderer

Subscribe the message in the constructor .

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, UIViewController > (this, "ViewWillDisappear",(arg,controller)=> {
            //  controller is the current UIViewController         
            
            });
```